# How to download and unpack .ZIP folder using Adobe Air?

Tags: actionscript-3, download, air, zip, unpack

How to download and unpack .ZIP folder  using Adobe Air? So I have http link onto that zip file example.com/zip.zip I need a function to download it onto users hard drive and unpack it into some folder on filesystem.

How to do such thing? (code example, please)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- [Using Zip files with Adobe Air, Flex
  and Flash | Psyked](http://www.psyked.co.uk/external-links/actionscript-30-lets-you-work-with-zip-files.htm)
- [FZip](http://codeazur.com.br/lab/fzip/)

FZip is an Actionscript 3 class library to load, modify and
            create standard ZIP archives.FZip parses ZIP archives progressively, allowing access            to contained files while the archive is loading.

Comment: In case anyone comes back here looking for answers FZip seems to have merged with the AS3 Commons library http://www.as3commons.org/as3-commons-zip/.  I've been able to use this to zip local files, but I've been running into issues where it sometimes get stuck when you do a file load and Event.COMPLETE never fires.  Doing the opposite however, is what this is about.  API Docs here http://www.as3commons.org/as3-commons-zip/asdoc/index.html.  I haven't found many cookbook style examples.